# Xamarin Forms Datepicker: Bind Nullable DateTime(DateTime?)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a nullable date field in my object and I want to bind a date picker to it. When the value is null, I want to show blank in the picker instead of currentdate shown on the picker. But, still allow user to select the date.

I referred the https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20028/datepicker-possible-to-bind-to-nullable-date-value

But Couldn't find the code for uwp renderer

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is currently not in UWP. And I have found the [feature request](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/16997776-xamarin-forms-datepicker-with-clear-button-to-allo) in the Xamarin Platform Suggestions, you could vote it up.

Comment: Sure. I anyways created custom control. If they come up something for nullable datetime picker, it will be a great feature.